# How to make Firebase database values only visible to their respective paired UIDs?

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, rules

This is my database structure:
[image: database structure]

I want the values under the node of user 1 only readable and writable to user 1, and the values under the node of user 2 only readable and writable to user 2, and so on for other new users in the future. That means user 1 cannot read and write values under the nodes of other users and vise versa.For that I had to set up a rule for my database.

---

**The rule below is what I tried.** So far, User 1 can only write values under his own node and does not write under the nodes of other users, and vise versa, which is exactly what I want. Problem is user 1 can still read values under  the nodes of other users, which is undesirable. I read some documents explaining the database rules but this is very hard for me to understand. I tried multiple ways to rewrite my rule but still failed. I need help to fix this.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write":"auth.uid != null",
    "Users' Input History": {
      "$user": {
      ".validate":"$user === auth.uid"
      }
    },

    "Users' Vocabulary List": {
      "$user": {
      ".validate":"$user === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the record, I used the rule simulator, as in the following images. I toggeled on the "validated" option, selected "Google" as the provider, set simulated UID as "Kad06bqeNChhjaksxgP9cVtoFMh1" (which is user 1), and hit the execute button. The result was both "read" and "set" permitted at line 3 and 4 respectively.

[image]

[image]

---

Below is my code for user authentication and submitting values to the database:

GoogleSignInActivity:

```
public class GoogleSignInActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    // [END declare_auth]

    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private TextView mStatusTextView; // For displaying user's email
    private TextView mDetailTextView; // For displaying user's UID
    private TextView mScreenNameTextView; // For displaying user's display name (user.getDisplayName())


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_sign_in);

        // Views
        mStatusTextView = findViewById(R.id.status);
        mDetailTextView = findViewById(R.id.detail);
        mScreenNameTextView = findViewById(R.id.screen_name_textView);

        setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar);

        // Button listeners
        findViewById(R.id.signInButton).setOnClickListener(this);


        // [START config_signin]
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // [END config_signin]

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        // [START initialize_auth]
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [END initialize_auth]



        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    toastMessage("Successfully signed in with: " + user.getEmail());
                    mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.Google_status_fmt, user.getEmail()));
                    mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.Firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));


                            username = mDetailTextView.getText().toString();

                }
            }
        };


    }



    // [START on_start_check_user]
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null).
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    }
    // [END on_start_check_user]


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }


    // [START onActivityResult]
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.Login_successful), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        username = mDetailTextView.getText().toString();


            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
    // [END onActivityResult]

    // [START auth_with_google]
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        showProgressBar();
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        hideProgressBar();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END auth_with_google]

    // [START signin]
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    // [END signin]


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.signInButton) {
            signIn();
        } 

    }


}
```

My code for pushing values to the database:

```
EditText wordInputView;
String searchKeyword; 
String username;

public static DatabaseReference mRootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    public static DatabaseReference mChildReferenceForInputHistory = mRootReference.child("Users' Input History");
    public static DatabaseReference mChildReferenceForVocabularyList = mRootReference.child("Users' Vocabulary List");

searchKeyword = wordInputView.getText().toString();


Query query = mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(username).orderByValue().equalTo(searchKeyword);

                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            //If a duplicate value (searchKeyword) is found, remove it.
                            snapshot.getRef().setValue(null);  
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        throw databaseError.toException();
                    }
                });

                mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(username).push().setValue(searchKeyword);



//Initialize the adapter
        userInputArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userInputArraylist);
        userInputListview.setAdapter(userInputArrayAdapter);
        mChildReferenceForInputHistory.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildKey) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);

                    userInputArraylist.add(value);


                    HashSet<String> myVocabularyArraylistHashSet = new HashSet<>();
                    myVocabularyArraylistHashSet.addAll(userInputArraylist);
                    userInputArraylist.clear();
                    userInputArraylist.addAll(myVocabularyArraylistHashSet);

                    //Alphabetic sorting
                    Collections.sort(userInputArraylist);

                    userInputArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Firebase documentation:

> If a rule grants read or write permissions at a particular path, then it also grants access to all child nodes under it.

In your case you are giving .read permissions to all users that are authenticated, because this part:

```
  "rules": {
".read": "auth.uid != null",
".write":"auth.uid != null",
```

... gives read permissions to everyone that is authenticated and because this is your route directory they also give them permissions to read "Users' Input History" and "Users' Vocabulary List" because this are under your route.

The .validate rules are used only when you are writing data and they define what the data should be.
Back to your question, in your usecase you should reconsider restructuring your database and setting new rules.
One possible solution is setting these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users' Input History": {
      "$user": {
            ".read": "auth.uid  === $user",
              ".write": "auth.uid  === $user"
      }
    },

    "Users' Vocabulary List": {
      "$user": {
            ".read": "auth.uid  === $user",
              ".write": "auth.uid  === $user"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case you give permissions to the user 111 to read and write only "/Users' Input History/111" and "/Users' Vocabulary List/111" so if you have more childs under root you must define rules for each one of them.

Comment: The rule you provided is unfortunately not working for my current database. User 1 can still read and write values from other users. I don't get which part of my code is possibly wrong or is there any workaround. I have a listView for displaying the values and that is how I know the rule is not working. I'm logged as as User 1 and I'm still seeing values submitted by user 2. I've updated my post with the listView and the array adapter. It's in the mChildReferenceForInputHistory.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {}) section.

Comment: Can you post your actual rules?

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by actual rules? The rules I'm actually using is already shown in my post, which is this:  {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write":"auth.uid != null",
    "Users' Input History": {
      "$user": {
      ".validate":"$user === auth.uid"
      }
    },

    "Users' Vocabulary List": {
      "$user": {
      ".validate":"$user === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}    I also tried your provided rule but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: So, this rules grant read access to everyone that is authtenticated because of the  ""rules": { ".read": "auth.uid != null", ".write":"auth.uid != null", "" part. Like I said in my comment this rules also grants access to all child nodes under it.  You should give a try the example I posted, but as is, just copy/paste it over ypur actual rules or better remove everything you have there first and paste the rules I provided. I tested it and it works fine.

Comment: I also edited my answer just to be more specific where your code fails.

Comment: Strange.  I copied/pasted your rule and now users can write values to their respective UIDs, but no users can read their own values anymore.

Comment: well, it should be something in the way you querying the database. can you post the method? *disclaimer I only know Dart and Swift, but should be able to understand your code.

Comment: The only database querry method I use is in the 8th line of the code block under the "My code for pushing values to the database:" line in my post. It starts with "Query query = mChildReferenceForInputHistory...." and you should be able to find it in my post. Note that when I change the position of this line: "mChildReferenceForInputHistory.child(username).push().setValue(searchKeyword);" , my database's write function would act strangely depending on how the database rule is changed. I suspecr that might be the culprit but maybe it's just me.

Comment: The existence of that querry is to find out duplicate values, then first delete the original value and then add the duplicate value, thus creating an illusion that the duplicate value replaces the original value. I did this so that the database won't have duplicate values and I don't know a better method otherwise. I suspect that could be a culprit too.

Comment: Well I think you should consider using update instead set, this way if value exists it just updates it. Despite that I think you should test the data your query returns and if there's data then reformat your code and if you struggle with the query you can post another question on Stackoverflow, but at the moment the code I provide should do the server part.

Comment: Will take that into account, i6x86.